# IndexError: too many indices for array in python (still error occur)

Tags: python, image

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Feb 22 15:09:13 2021

@author: 
"""

import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy

...
...
...
...
        

        thickness = int(pointsarray[1,0]) - int(pointsarray[0,0])  #here is the error
        print(thickness)              
        cv2.line(img, (cx, cy), (cx+50, cy), (0,0,255), 1)
        cv2.putText(img, 'Thickness : '+str(thickness),(x-20, y-10), font, 0.4,(0,0,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

The following error occurs:

thickness = int(pointsarray[1,0]) - int(pointsarray[0,0])
IndexError: too many indices for array

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2D array try this:

```py
thickness = int(pointsarray[1][0]) - int(pointsarray[0][0])
```

list object needs to be accessed separately, or you can use numpy arrays